# ArguementOutOfRangeException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, datagridview

i'm very new to programming and c#. here i'm having ArguementOutOfRangeException. i want to add a new data row to the datagridview every time when click the button. so i used a variable "i" to increase the value one by one and change the row value when i use "0" which means

```
dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
```

instead of "i" the first row fills but when use "1" which means

```
dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
```

the exception comes. what is the right way to do such a thing ?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public SqlConnection conn;
    public int i = 0;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=sspi; Initial Catalog=student");
        conn.Open();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Sqlstr = "insert into student(name, pw)values(@name,@pw)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sqlstr, conn);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", textBox2.Text);


        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            i++;
            DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();

        }
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define a new `DataGridView` each time on a button click, I believe you want to add a new row in your existing `DataGridView` after the insert in database. You can do:

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView2.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    row.Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the best answer :) . i'm very new to C# so i don't know these stuffs well. very hard to know every fact :(

Comment: can you explain DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView2.Rows[0].Clone(); 
what happening here ?

Comment: @user2566013, its just making a copy of the first row's structure, so if you have any kind of formatting rules applied to the columns, they will be used for the new row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new rows before you try writing in them. Use `dataGridView2.Rows.Add( something )`, check out the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.